# Copying and Renaming xhtml file to new file in JSF causing data does not load

Tags: jsf

I received an assignment to have a look at Java Server Faces project and maintain the existing code if possible. My background is ASP.net , and never made a Java program previously. The problem is like this : there is existing file code named policy_list.xhtml (with also several beans attached to UI component in the file) and lets say it attach to menu Policy List. If user click the menu, the policy_list.xhtml will show the list of Policy. I copied the policy_list.xhtml file and renamed it to a new file renewal_list.xhtml. And I created a new menu Renewal List and attach the link to renewal_list.xhtml. I did not make any changes to renewal_list.xhtml. However , when I click the Renewal List menu, the page did not show any data like the Policy List menu. There is no error shown in the page What is wrong with the Renewal List page. Is it the behaviour of JSF ? On the IntelliJ IDEA debugger, I have not found any error. However the Search button in the renewal_list.xhtml working fine just as policy_list.xhtml. All the action link in the dataTable does not work in renewal_list.xhtml. I guess I am missing as particular setup on the menu or else ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

My God, I have to registered it on pages.xml . Now, its working. Thanks to the powerful search of IntelliJ idea.